# How to set up NTP (not SNTP) on a Windows box?

Tags: windows-7, ntp, ntpd, brocade

I have a network that is running on Brocade layer 3 switches.  I need these switches to be synced with NTP.  The computer that I need to use is running Windows 7 and has services such as Win32time that use SNTP but no native NTP support.  So far I have tried using the SNTP to serve the switches as this should work in theory based on the SNTP RFC 2030.  I was able to verify that SNTP was working correctly with a Brocade FCX layer 3 switch but the ICX switches didn't work.

My next thought was to use the NTPd windows port.  I have had nothing but issues with it from config files not working to the service flat out failing to start.  I have tried it with the Meinberg companion tool found at https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/sw/ntp-server-monitor.htm  I have also tried it by itself.

At this point I am looking for any way to reliably serve NTP from a Windows 7 computer.  If anyone has any tools they use or a really good walk through of the NTPd windows port setup that would be perfect.

This application must use ***NTP not SNTP.***

Comment: You need a NTP server ? as the NTP client in Windows is not full featured, but it work. For such need you need the registry key : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ System \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ W32Time \ TimeProviders \ NtpServer  | Enabled 0 > 1. Does it's more a native VLAN issue ? from where the switch send it's request ?

Comment: I tried an implementation of that but it is serving sntp not ntp.  Is there a different bit to change to make it ntp?

Comment: So you're looking for a product recommendation *and* a tutorial for it, so you can loop an out-of-mainstream-support desktop OS into your network infrastructure? Quadruply off-topic in one question - achievement.  (Also the meinberg port of NTP (which worksforme(tm) has a wizard installer and even has a link to a tutorial on their own install page http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/setup.html)

Comment: What where your issues with the ntp port for windows? it works OK and you should be able to get it up and running with a simple config file. Best bet (IMO) is to run a linux box internally for ntp but if you want help with trying to get the ntpd port working post another question on here or stackoverflow